# Can I install apiman 1.0.0.Beta1 on WildFly 8.2

Tags: jboss, compatibility, backwards-compatibility, apiman

The apiman (http://www.apiman.io/latest/download.html) tell to use the (WildFly 8.1.0.Final) but the latest version of WildFly is 8.2

Can I install apiman on 8.2 version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that shouldn't be a problem. In fact, if you check out the latest apiman releases it uses WildFly 8.2 for its quickstarts and quick development setup (server-all).

If you want something that will allow you get apiman up and running quickly for playing, testing or developing with, then clone the apiman repo (https://github.com/apiman/apiman.git), and run:

```
cd apiman
mvn clean install -Pinstall-all-wildfly8
cd tools/server-all/target/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/
./bin/standalone.sh
```

After that fires up, open `http://localhost:8080/apiman-manager` and log in with u: `admin` p: `admin123!`

It's seeded with some basic data so you can dive right in: roles, users, an attached gateway, etc.

Comment: If you're using a newer version of apiman, the URI might be `http://localhost:8080/apimanui`. Also, check out the [quickstarts](http://www.apiman.io/latest/download.html) here. There's docker and a WF setup you can have running in a flash.